# Finding the points which have equal area under the curve for Gausian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, area, gaussian

I have a normal distribution N(1,0) and have to split it in n-pieces where the area under the curve is equal i.e. 1/n

Now I need to find the specific points/values where this happen.

```
  f(1 .. n) =
```

How do I do that ? If you can provide pseudo code it will be good too i.e. i need to make it python code.

PS> I'm trying to implement this :

[https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.pdf](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/SAX.pdf)

page 5 : Discretization

I hope I'm describing the problem OK!
I'm abit confused by why they need table, instead of just list of numbers i.e. points/values.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi^{-1}$ be the quantile function of the standard normal distribution, then the points
$$\Phi^{-1}(0),\Phi^{-1}(\frac1n), \Phi^{-1}(\frac2n),\dots\Phi^{-1}(\frac{n-1}{n}),\Phi^{-1}(1),$$
where $\Phi^{-1}(0)=-\infty$ and $\Phi^{-1}(1)=\infty$, will divide the real line into intervals, which each have probability $\frac{1}{n}$ with respect to a $N(0,1)$ distribution.

Let's verify this. Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then
\begin{align*}
P(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{k}{n}) \leq Z \leq \Phi^{-1}(\frac{k+1}{n}))  &= \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{k+1}{n}))-\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{k}{n})) \\ &= \frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n} \\ &= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
The quantile function $\Phi^{-1}$ can be computed in Python with the norm.ppf() function from the scipy.stats module https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html .